# Cucumber - what's the difference between these two givens?

Tags: cucumber, mapping, bdd, gherkin

New to this whole BDD world, and I'm already experiencing weird behavior.

So in the three "Given" statements below, they all refer to the ints in the table, right? So I thought when mapping (see second pic), I just replace all the "<...>" tags with "{int}", but that's not the case. , , ,  stay the same and are not replaced by `{int}`, but  is replaced by `{int}.`

Is this normal? If so, what's the rule?
[image]

[image]

Comment: In the step definition (second image) you have the argument's name (ex: xRow, xCol etc), and not it's value (ex: 2, 1, 3 etc), that's normal. Btw when you use scenario outline and the passed value is part of the table, the correct gherkin step is :    Given An X is added at "<xRow>", "<xCol>"    and the corresponding step definition would be :    @Given("^An X is added at \"([^\"]*)\", \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void anXIsAddedAt(String xRow, String xCol)  {
     //Write your code here 
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your step definition, where you specify which text should be matched by your step, you need to specify which Cucumber expression should be matched.

Change the first two step definitions to:
`@Given("An X is added at row {int}, {int})`
and 
`@Given("An O is added at row {int}, {int})`

(*Sidenote on asking questions*: next time please copy your feature file and code into your question. That makes it easier to answer using your snippets.)

Answer (score 0):

Your step definition for gherkin steps Given An X .... and Given An O.... does not meet the required criteria to accept the int parameter. In step definition when a integer value is expected to be received as parameter you must use {int} or (\d+). Which means your step definition for first two given statement would be as follow

```
@Given("^An X is added at row {int}, {int}$")
@Given("^An O is added at row {int}, {int}$")
```